# Unity camera rotation script shaking camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a camera that can be rotated by using the mouse, but for some reason the camera jitters and shakes when I move the mouse.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using static UnityEngine.RuleTile.TilingRuleOutput;

public class rotatecamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject camera;
    public float turnSpeed = 4.0f;
    private float rotX;
    private void Update()
    {

        rotX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turnSpeed;
        camera.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, 0, 0);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rotating by 4 degrees per frame.

The frame rate will depend on your FPS, but it is probably going to be at least 60.

Thus you will be rotating up to 240 degrees per second. That's probably not what you want.

You should use

```
 new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
```

Time.deltaTime will give you the elapsed time since the previous frame. This will give a rate of rotation up to 4 degrees per second.

You might also want to consider using FixedUpdate where the update rate is fixed and use Time.fixedDeltaTime.

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason now my camera moves in both axes. I used the block of code above and replaced it with my old code.

Comment: I have no idea what you did without seeing your code, but my advice is correct and would have nothing to with it rotating in more than one axis. The advice is to multiply the rotation by the delta time.

Comment: It's moving, just it keeps shaking for some reason.